# Total commander can't open file in OneDrive folder

Tags: total-commander

I use `Total Commander Version 9.0a 64bit)`, also I have `OneDrive` connected to path `c:\users\[MyUserName]\OneDrive`.

The problem is the following: if I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> on any file in the Onedrive folder, I got a popup

> File not found

However, if I open the context menu and I select the filename (the top item), it works just fine (.exe is executed, .pdf opens pdf viewer, .xlsx opens Excel, etc.).

Also, opening a file by <kbd>enter</kbd> works in every other folder.

Any ideas why this specific folder behaves differently and why <kbd>enter</kbd> is handled differently then using the local menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made an Update to TotalCommander (installed Version 9.10) - Problem gone. I don't know why, but now it's working "normal" again.